# Find value with same value in string ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 201453 | 1000 |
| Cell 2 | 201232 | 1000 |
| Cell 3 | 213231 | 2000 |
| Cell 2 | 201233 | 3000 |
| Cell 1 | 200032 | 1000 |

- Column A - may be repeated
- Column B - unique
- Column C - may be repeated

How do I find value (column A), which have same value (column C)?

I don't get it...

Comment: `SELECT col_a ... GROUP BY col_a,col_c HAVING COUNT(*)>1` : You want only to return `Cell 1` as result, don't you? (welcome to SO)

Comment: What would be desired output, based on sample data you posted?

Comment: Barbaros Özhan
Right! Ty!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the request right, you need to know each value os `columnA` that has the same value in `ColumnC`:

```
select LISTAGG("Column A",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Column A") from table1
group by "Column C"
```

### test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/303780/5

Comment: yes, noticed that while doing the test.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to count the duplicates for values of `col_a` vs. `col_c` pair . So, using a `HAVING` clause along with grouping by those two columns will do the trick such as

```
SELECT col_a
  FROM t
 GROUP BY col_a,col_c 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/G79TbF86)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for rows having the same (repeated) combination of COL_A and COL_C then try this:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "COL_A", 201453 "COL_B", 1000 "COL_C" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "COL_A", 201232 "COL_B", 1000 "COL_C" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3 "COL_A", 213231 "COL_B", 2000 "COL_C" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "COL_A", 201233 "COL_B", 3000 "COL_C" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 1 "COL_A", 200032 "COL_B", 1000 "COL_C" From Dual            
        )

SELECT
    COL_A, COL_B, COL_C
FROM
    ( Select  COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, 
              Count(COL_B) OVER(Partition By COL_A, COL_C) "COUNT_A_C" 
      From    tbl )
WHERE   COUNT_A_C > 1

R e s u l t :
     COL_A      COL_B      COL_C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1     201453       1000 
         1     200032       1000
```

Used analytic function Count() Over() - more about analytic functions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174).

... Or with aggregate function Count(), Group By and Having - the result is the same as above

```sql
SELECT    t.COL_A, t.COL_B, t.COL_C
FROM      tbl t
INNER JOIN 
    ( Select  COL_A, COL_C, Count(COL_B) "COUNT_A_C" 
      From    tbl
      Group By COL_A, COL_C
      Having Count(COL_B) > 1) c ON (c.COL_A = t.COL_A And c.COL_C = t.COL_C)
```